# store values in array from loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code to try to create and array of values to use then in a map to print the value names in cards (bootstrap).

```
const { user } = useAuth();
    const {
        responsable,
        editor,
    } = user;      
    
    const uniqueDCentros = Array.from(new 
     Set(JSON.parse(responsable).concat(JSON.parse(editor))));
    
    const getTopics = useSelector((state)=> state.topics); // i received from reducer 
     //the **topics** everytime that the **initFetch** execute the loop that is inside.

    const [uniqueTopics, setUniqueTopics] = useState([])
    
    let resTopics = [];            
    for(let topic of getTopics) {            
        resTopics.push(topic.topicName)        
    }

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const initFetch = useCallback(() => {        
        for (let dc of uniqueDCentros) {            
            dispatch(getTopicsbyDcentro(dc)); // get the 'topics' for every 'dc' that i want to use together, 
                }
    }, dispatch);        
    
    useEffect(() => {        
        initFetch(); 
        setUniquetopics([restTopics, ...uniqueTopics])               
    }, initFetch);
```

I would like to store all the **topics** to use later.
I tryed with push inside the loop, and with useState() to store the values, but not works.

Some help for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have topics on state in redux. Therefore you don't need to copy that state into this component. You can simply access it like

```
const topics = getTopics.map(t => t.topicName);
```

Edit: it would be easiest to keep all the results on redux, but in case you don't want to do that for some reason, keep track of each element that the component reacts to.

```
const useAccumulate = (list) => {
  const [acc, setAcc] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Every time the reference for the list updates
    // add every element into the accumulator
    setAcc(a => [...a, ...list]);
  }, [list]);

  return acc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the topics, change everytime that the useEffect execute initFetch(). In this case execute initFetch() 3 times, one for each 'dc' and return differents topics everyTime.

Comment: So the redux is not accumulating all of these elements, but you instead want to keep track of all of the known ones through the lifetime of this component?

Comment: Yes i need to store all the values that topics state return, for everytime that initFetch() is executed.

Comment: Thanks for your time, at the end i did find the way to acumulate the values in redux. Using state.push(...action.payload) inside the reducer.

Comment: Cool. FYI push is a mutating function. Redux (and react) are built with the intention that you only use immutable data structures and operations. To add elements to a list in an immutable way, make a new list with the spread operator. Like `const newList = [...oldList, ...action.payload]`

Comment: Great info, but FYI. Redux Toolkit's createReducer and createSlice automatically use Immer internally to let you write simpler immutable update logic using "mutating" syntax. This helps simplify most reducer implementations. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers. So i think that use state.push(...action.payload) with redux toolkit should works find. what do you think?

Comment: yes, do the thing that your library recommends to avoid mutation